# SQL Server: why would you ever cast on the left side of an operator?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, join, casting

I am using SQL Server 2005.

I was coding with a friend of mine and just for an example I went to cast a join on the left side.

```
JOIN t on cast(a.foo as int) = b.foo
```

He told me never to do this as I loose all the performance benefits of indexing.

Why would you ever want to intentionally do this?

Comment: The best choice is to refactor so that fields you will be joining on have the same data type.

Comment: Yes, naturally that is what we did, however I was just curious regarding a left side cast :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well... The answer is sort of what your friend said. If you cast it, it won't be able to take advantage indices on a.foo. However if you cast the right side then you won't be able take advantage of indices on b.foo.

In the end, if you're joining mismatched data types you're going to have to lose somewhere. Whether it should be on the left or right hand side of a join depends entirely on the data density, and what indices are actually on the tables involved(e.g. It really doesn't cost a whole lot if a.foo isn't indexed anyway).

Answer (score 0):

When writing temporal predicate such as

> `@test_date` falls within the close-open period bounded by `T.start_date`
>   and `T.end_date`

I have a strong preference for locating the smaller date on the left hand side, as would be the case on a timeline i.e.

```
WHERE T.start_date <= @test_date
      AND @test_date < T.end_date
```

If `@test_date` involved a `CAST` I would write it the same way initially. In all honesty, I would probably only seek to change it if there was a performance issue because a favour logically sound, readable code over premature optimization.